# Multiple site domains and virtual directory single login

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am creating a project which has a login portal with multiple applications and websites. I want to allow the user to login and then click any application and have access to it. Some considerations are: each application is defined in a user profile, ie which users can see what. also each application privileges are different for each user. so user a may be an administrator of application a but just a normal users in application b.

**What i know.**

I can have one auth cookie created in the main portal which with setting the machine key and same authcookie name, each application can use it. I have done a test with this and it seems to work.

**My problem**

As each site/ virtual directory has different privileges per user and per application when the user access a site i need to get his privileges from the databases but I cant then overwrite the auth cookie userdata with the new details because he may have multiple tabs etc open at a time on different sites. So how can i have an extra cookie store per user and per application for holding application specific details. I know I could go to the database each time but that's allot of overhead for each post back.

Maybe another option is to use the main authcooke for checking the user is logged in then have a new auth cookie per aplication and user, but how can i have 2 authcookies, that may get confusing and the second needs to timeout when the main one does et c i think

Any help suggestions would be gratefully appreciated

THanks

------------------- **EDIT** -----------------------------

we have one user table for all all sites not 1 per each site. then we map the user to an application and then the user application and role. so when you get to an application it has to check if the user has access and what there role is. all other user details are already in the auth cookie when loggedinto the main site. We do it this way because we have to manage users in one application not each application. Hope this helps understand my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a 'classic' SSO (single sign-on) example. There are lots of ways people have tried this and they are well documented on Google.

One way to do this is to have your SSO server (e.g. the first place you land and log in) to issue a security 'token' (e.g. a Guid) and then either store this in a cookie or append to URLs. Each subsequent call to an application can look-up the token in a database, verify it's validity and carry on (or boot the user out if invalid).

Using a database also allows you to set a timeout for all applications for which the token is valid.

This can then be extended to allow the database to store which apps each user can access etc. I've described this in very broad terms but it may be a good starting point.

Hope this helps

BTW: querying the database on each request isn't too much of an overhead. I have applications that do just that and are still performant when loaded with 300+ users.

Comment: thankyou dave for your help. 
What i have done so far is to create an auth cookie in the main website which all other apps can use so the guid you mention could just be the username i guess. I will search google for sso instead this time. you have any good example with code. i have edited the question forgot to mention we only have 1 usertable. then each application reference that table for user details. then off the users table is applicationUserRoles where the user and application are linked and the users roles ie admin, statndard, reader etc

Comment: unfotunately I cannot give code samples becuase they are quite large and, more importantly, a protected asset of my company and I don't want to breach IP. I'll try and find some other examples...

Comment: Have a look at this (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106439/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic) I haven't read it all but it looks similar to what I'm talking about.

Comment: Also, do not carry username in the cookie. If you think about it you need two pieces of information to authenticate, username and password. If you carry username in a cookie then you've halved the work needed by a hacker. Use a 'throw away' value instead that can be referenced back to the user in the database.

Comment: i have encrypted the auth cookie, do you feel thats not good enough.

Comment: If you've encrypted it then it should be fine. I guess I'm just paranoid about putting 'real' values out there ;)

Comment: thanks, i am reading the link you sent. thanks for your help.

Comment: i have read the article you mentioned and quite a few others. i am now more confused on how to implement this. Is there any more help/ advice you can give me based on my question edit above. there will be approx 20 applications under the 1 website. i have implemented custom identity so i can get at user details in userdata of the cookie. I just dont know how to store handle each applications access unless i goto database each time which is possible as you say, but for certain things like user type it seems unnecasary. any advise really appreciated. i am reading articles but dont help. thanks